# Left and right align some of the tick labels in x-axis of a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have below `ggplot`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales) 
df <- data.frame("levs" = c("a long label i want to wrap",
                            "another also long label"),
                 "vals" = c(1,2))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = levs, y = vals)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +  
  coord_flip() + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = wrap_format(20))
```

With this I am getting following plot

[image]

I am wondering if I can `left align` and `right align` leftmost and rightmost `tick labels` (i.e. 0.0 and 2.0) respectively. Basically in my actual plot, I have big -negative and positive numbers at these two place and they are overflowing the plot area.

Any input is very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify different `hjust()` in `theme()`

**Code**

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = levs, y = vals)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +  
  coord_flip() + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = wrap_format(20)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-20000, 20000, by = 10000)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust=c(0, 0.5,0.5,0.5, 1)))
```

**Output**

[image]

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame("levs" = c("a long label i want to wrap",
                            "another also long label"),
                 "vals" = c(-20000,20000))
```